# Cannot access jupyterlab inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running this configuration in a VM where I ssh into with port forwarding.

```
ssh ... -L 8888:localhost:8888
```

Inside the VM I start the docker container with

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

---

Given the following input:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.3"
   
services:
  deltalake:
    build: .
    command: jupyter-lab --allow-root --no-browser --host 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8888:8888"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM databricksruntime/standard:9.x

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    
RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

ENV PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN conda --version && conda install jupyterlab
```

---

I see the server is running on port 8888 inside the container, but I cannot access it.

When I go to the browser I get page is not working and inside the VM:

```
curl localhost:8888
> curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I tired different combination of urls and bindings such as `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0`, but nothing worked. Is there any thing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `--host` into `--ip` in your `command` in `docker-compose`.

```
command : jupyter-lab --allow-root --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0
```

now it should work.